# Trying to monitor JGroups with probe.sh

Tags: jgroups

I'm trying to monitor the multicast traffic between JGroups members. I see there's a tool probe.sh which invokes org.jgroups.tests.Probe. However, it does not produce any effect. Is this tool still working?
Example:

```
java -cp jgroups-4.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar org.jgroups.tests.McastReceiverTest -mcast_addr 224.0.75.75 -port 7500 -bind_addr 127.0.0.1
java -cp jgroups-4.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar org.jgroups.tests.McastSenderTest -mcast_addr 224.0.75.75 -port 7500 -bind_addr 127.0.0.1
```

Now, while sending and receiving messages:

```
java -cp jgroups-4.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar org.jgroups.tests.Probe -mcast_addr 224.0.75.75 -port 7500 

0 responses (0 matches, 0 non matches)
```

This happens on whatever command I try to pass to Probe class. From the documentation it should at least print "-send probe on /224.0.75.75:7500" but it doesn't print anything. 
I've tried also running Probe against wildfly application server (with jgroups diagnostics enabled on that address/port) but still "0 responses"

Answer (score 0):

Run a real JGroups program, such as Draw, as McastSender/ReceiverTest don't use JGroups!